# Обмен данными по ModBus

Tags: c#, modbus

***Добрый день!***

Помогите с обменом данных по **ModBus**. При обращении к мультиметру **PM1000** я знаю что его **ID = 123** но возвращаемое значение приходит совсем другое например **17589** или что-то в этом роде и так со всеми параметрами(вольтаж,ампераж) практически все параметры возвращаются в пределах 
***от 17000 до 18000*** и не важно какое значение ему присвоено будь то **1** может все равно вернуться ***17541*** и будь то **12500** может вернуться ***17444***).
В чем может быть проблема?
Адаптер написан на **C#** с ним проблем нету. Этот же адаптер прекрасно работает с другими устройствами и правильно возвращает значения.
Уже около недели не могу разобраться.

**Заранее благодарю!**

Comment: Попробуй воспользоваться готовым адаптером: https://github.com/NModbus/NModbus
Если с ним проблем не возникнет, значит виновата всё-таки ваша реализация. Другие устройства могли не использовать те части протокола, которые породили проблему.

Comment: Спасибо большое попробовал но результат тот же самый

Comment: Может что-то не то  внастройках самого устройства(мультиметра)  Например baudrate или еще где-то но не думаю что из-за этого может неправильные значения возвращать он либо возвращает либо должен ошибку выдавать вроде

Comment: в таком случае, проблема не в вашем коде, а в устройстве. Либо оно общается посредством некорректного протокола, либо вовсе работает неправильно. Стоит связаться с производителем и уточнить этот вопрос у них.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое еще раз.Думаю да надо будет все-таки с производитеоями поговорить.Если вдруг еще что-то в голову придет сообщите пожалуйста.Благодарю и если проблема решится я отпишусь

Comment: Ааа еще забыл добавить!!! на самом мультиметре данные отображаются нормально то есть заходишь в раздел где ID он показывает что ID = 123(на экране самого мультиметра)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ребята проблема решилась оказывается данные приходили в виде стандарта IEEE

Если нужно просто конвертировать Int32 в эквивалентное (по байтовому представлению) IEEE Float, это можно сделать проще:

```
Int32 number = 0x43c8840e;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (BinaryWriter wr = new BinaryWriter(ms))
    using (BinaryReader rd = new BinaryReader(ms))
    {
        wr.Write(number);
        wr.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        float f = rd.ReadSingle();
        Console.WriteLine(f);
    }
}
```

Правда, не вижу особого смысла в этой операции. Если данные приходят во float надо и считывать сразу float. C# работу с ним полностью поддерживает.

Comment: Можно ещё проще: float f = BitConverter.ToSingle(BitConverter.GetBytes(0x43c8840e), 0);

Comment: спасибо большое ребята вы лучшие

Comment: Единственное "что" MSDN.WhiteKnight в вашем случае не работает с отрицательными числами

Answer (score 1):

Ребята проблема решилась оказывается данные приходили в виде стандарта IEEE

```
char[] ch = new char[8];
        string s = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32("43c8840e", 16), 2);
        double deci = 0;
        int b = 0;
        //Console.WriteLine(s);
        string dec = s.Substring(0, 8);
        // Console.WriteLine(dec);
        string frac = s.Substring(8, s.Length - 8);
        //Console.WriteLine(frac);
        int a = Convert.ToInt32(dec, 2);
        int exp = a - 127;
        double[] fracarray = new double[frac.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < frac.Length; i++)
        {
            b++;
            fracarray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(frac[i] - 48) * Math.Pow(2, -b);
            deci += fracarray[i];
        }
        double finala = Math.Pow(2, exp) * (1 + deci);
        Console.WriteLine(finala);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

вот этот кусочек кода помог во всем разобраться

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте.

В вашем вопросе недостаточно данных для ответа.

Во первых, нет гарантий, что адаптер правильный. В моей практике были случаи, когда код работал нормально, а на новом устройстве выдавал ошибку.
Во вторых вы не указали функции, которые использовали для чтения и записи. Также было бы неплохо указать какие регистры устройства предназначены для записи, а какие для чтения (нет желания читать спецификацию указанного вами устройства и выдирать данные оттуда).
И, соответственно, код, который пишет и читает данные.

Так же есть ModBus RTU и ModBus TCP, вы не указали какой случай у вас. И еще ModBus поддерживает несколько устройств, соединенных шиной. Какие устройства и как подключены к порту не понятно, так как вы указываете только одно.

Comment: ModBus TCP, Информацию получал не только по написанному мной адаптору а использовал готовые с ними такая же история Вот и я думаю может элетрики неправильно установили или подключили этот мультиметр,думал если кто встречался с такой проблемой напишет как решил и в чем была проблема а подключено обычно на мультиметре есть выход ModBus + - оттуда он подключался к MOXA MGATE и с MOXA к моему порту на ноуте и все